# JavaCompiler, StandardJavaFileManager throws NPE

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation, jar, compiler-errors

I want to compile a class from another class but every method I used throws a NullPointerException.

Here's the code:

```
File fRun = new File(fileToRun);    
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
// NPE IN NEXT LINE
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(fRun);
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compUnits).call();            
fileManager.close();
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileToCompile = "test" + java.io.File.separator + "MyClass.java";
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    // NPE IN NEXT LINE
    int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
    if (compilationResult == 0) {
        System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
    }
}
```

from http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html

I start the program from Eclipse.

Wheres the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely getSystemJavaCompiler() returns null because there is no Java compiler provided on the platform you are running this on.  Are you running your program with JDK or with JRE?

Comment: can't have access to the source ATM but I think I'm running it with JRE 1.7

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `compiler` variable is `null` in your case. The documentation states that this can happen if you call it in an environment where you don't have a compiler available, e.g. just using a JVM, not a JDK installation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler()

Make sure you run the program using a full JDK that has a compiler available.